# Concatenating nvarchar(max) values doesn't seem to work (+= working as =)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Using SQL Server 2012, I've found that trying to build up a string based on an nvarchar(max) column in a table doesn't seem to work correctly. It seems to overwrite, instead of append.  Arbitrary Example:

```
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
    SELECT @sql = N'';
    SELECT @sql += [definition] + N'
GO
'
    FROM sys.sql_modules 
    WHERE OBJECT_NAME(object_id) LIKE 'dt%'
    ORDER BY OBJECT_NAME(object_id);

    PRINT @sql;
```

This SHOULD print out all the SQL module definitions for all the various dt_ tables in the database, separated by GO, as a script that could then be run. However... this prints out only the LAST module definition, not the sum of all of them. It's behaving as if the "+=" were just an "=".

If you change it just slightly... cast [definition] to an nvarchar(4000) for example, it suddenly works as expected. Also, if you choose any other column that is NOT an nvarchar(max) or varchar(max) type, it works as expected. Example:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
SELECT @sql = N'';
SELECT @sql += CAST([definition] AS nvarchar(4000)) + '
GO
'
FROM sys.sql_modules 
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(object_id) LIKE 'dt%'
ORDER BY OBJECT_NAME(object_id);

PRINT @sql;
```

Is this a known bug? Or is this working as expected? Am I doing something wrong? Is there any way for me to make this work correctly? I've tried a dozen different things, including ensuring every expression in the concatenation is the same nvarchar(max) type, including the string literal.

NOTE: The example is just an example that shows the problem, and not exactly what I'm trying to do in real life. If your database doesn't have the "dt*" tables defined, you can change the WHERE clause to specify any group of tables or stored procedures in any database you want, you'll get the same result... only the last one shows up in the @sql string, as if you just did "=" instead of "+=". Also, explicitly stating "@sql = @sql + " behaves the same way... works correctly with every string type EXCEPT nvarchar(max) or varchar(max).

I've verified that none of the [definition] values is NULL as well, so there are no NULL shenanigans going on.

Comment: Aside: Concatenating values using `for xml` as described [here](https://davegugg.wordpress.com/2015/01/29/creating-a-comma-separated-list-with-for-xml-path-and-stuff/) is reliable.

Comment: To add on to @HABO's comment, the behavior of aggregate string concatenation is undefined and results are plan dependent. You must use the XML PATH method or STRING_AGG() in later SQL Server versions.

Comment: try this outside of SSMS, try it in like LinqPad or any other external tool

Comment: Not a recommended way of doing this. From [`SET @local_variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks): "Do not use a variable in a SELECT statement to concatenate values (that is, to compute aggregate values). Unexpected query results may occur. This is because all expressions in the SELECT list (including assignments) are not guaranteed to be executed exactly once for each output row"

Comment: Interesting... as when I use normal string types, it has always worked reliably for me, on every version of SQL Server from 2005 to 2017. I've only ever experienced this issue with varchar(max) types.

Comment: @DanGuzman The XML PATH solution doesn't work either for two reasons: 1) No control over order as ORDER BY isn't allowed, and 2) It xml-encodes the string so that all CR/LFs get turned into &#x0D; strings. UGH! I need to concatenate varchar(max) columns together in a specific order, exactly as is, with no transcoding or html/xml encoding.

Comment: @HABO See my comment to Dan just above... for xml doesn't give me order, and seems to xml-encode the string so that CRs are turned into &#0D; strings. I can get around the latter by doing a REPLACE after the fact, but I still have the order issue.

Comment: @pmbAustin, FOR XML does honor the `ORDER BY` clause. I added an example.

Comment: Thanks, every time I tried to add an ORDER BY it threw errors saying ORDER BY wasn't valid...

Answer (score 1):

The += operator only applies to numeric data types in SQL Server. [Microsoft documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/add-equals-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

For string concatenation, you need to write the assignment and concatenation separately.

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
SELECT @sql = N'';
SELECT @sql = @sql + [definition] + N'
GO
'
FROM sys.sql_modules 
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(object_id) LIKE 'dt%'
ORDER BY OBJECT_NAME(object_id);

PRINT @sql;
```

Also, if you are running this query in Management Studio, keep in mind that there is a limit to the size of the data that it will return (including in a print statement). So if the definitions of your modules exceed this limit, they will be truncated in the output.

Comment: += is not only for numeric data types. In your link you missed at the bottom of the page there is another link for string concat https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/string-concatenation-equal-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Good catch. This might actually just be an oddity about how the += string concatenation operation works within a select statement. It looks like maybe SQL Server only processes the assignment once.

Comment: But as I said in the question, changing it to "@sql = @sql + " doesn't fix it or change it. And the "+=" works fine for all the other string types as well... just not varchar(max) or nvarchar(max). And if you create your own table with a varchar(max) column and just put short strings in it, you get the same behavior. It's apparently not an "amount of data" problem.

Answer (score 1):

To add on to @HABO's comment, the behavior of aggregate string concatenation is undefined and results are plan dependent. Use FOR XML to provide deterministic results and honor the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SET @sql = 
(SELECT [definition] + N'
GO
'
FROM sys.sql_modules 
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(object_id) LIKE 'dt%'
ORDER BY OBJECT_NAME(object_id)
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(MAX)');

PRINT @sql; --SSMS will truncate long strings
```

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
SELECT @sql =COALESCE(@sql + N' GO ','')+[definition]
FROM sys.sql_modules 


Print @sql;
```

Comment: Nope, I get the exact same behavior... after the SELECT, the @sql variable only contains the [definition] for the LAST row... not the concatenation of all of the definitions for all rows returned, as desired and expected.

Comment: It is because of ORDER BY. 
I copy/pasted your original code and it is working as expected on my side when I comment out ORDER BY. 
Whereas if ORDER BY is active, then it is showing just the last row.

Comment: No, it is not even an ORDER BY. If you ORDER BY object_id everything works properly, so the issue is OBJECT_NAME function. Since sorting is important to you, to do the workaround , you can try the following, it worked for me:
`select [definition], OBJECT_NAME(object_id) as obj_name
into #tmp
FROM sys.sql_modules 

   DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
    SELECT @sql = N'';
    SELECT @sql += [definition] + N'
GO
'
    FROM #tmp 
    ORDER BY obj_name
    PRINT @sql;`

Answer (score 0):

I´m pretty sure the PRINT command is the reason for the troubles.

When I try:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';
SELECT @sql += SUBSTRING( [definition], 1, 100 ) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'GO' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
FROM SYS.SQL_MODULES 
PRINT @sql;
```

I get all my procedures (the first 100 chars ...). So it seems to be a limitation to the PRINT command.

Second try, another database, without "substring":

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';
SELECT @sql += [definition] + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'GO' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
FROM SYS.SQL_MODULES 
PRINT @sql;
```

Now I got 1,5 procedures: The 1st one complete, the second stopped in the middle of on line in the proc. There is a limit in PRINT

Third try, to proof my assumption:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';
SELECT @sql += [definition] + 'GO' FROM SYS.SQL_MODULES 
PRINT @sql;
```

Now I got one line of code more! So for me, this is the proof, that PRINT has somehow a limit.

A last attempt:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';
SELECT @sql += [definition] + N'GO' FROM SYS.SQL_MODULES 
PRINT SUBSTRING(@SQL,1,4000)
PRINT SUBSTRING(@SQL,4001,4000)
```

The result: Now I got more then 2 procedures, although there now is a line break after 4K, this may occur on ... bad places.

Comment: I really don't think this is it. I've also used a WHILE loop to PRINT out just one line at a time. It only gets the last one, not all of them. I think in your example the SUBSTRING is converting the value to a nvarchar(100) or something, so it "works". If you leave it at varchar(max), it doesn't. You can create your own table with a varchar(max) and just put short strings in it to duplicate as well. The += concatenation just doesn't seem to work with varchar(max) columns.

Comment: @pmbAustin: Maybe your idea of "converting" has something to do with it. I edited the question to test it on another database. And the result was: 1 got 1,5 procedures: the first was ok, the second was broken (stopped in the middle)

Answer (score 0):

The following code demonstrates taking a column value from a set of ordered rows and, using `for xml`, creating an aggregated string with separators, including line breaks, between values.

```
-- Carriage return and linefeed characters.
declare @CRLF as NVarChar(16) = NChar( 13 ) + NChar( 10 );
-- Carriage return and linefeed characters XML encoded.
declare @EncodedCRLF as NVarChar(16) = N'&#13;&#10;';
-- Separator to insert between source rows in the accumulated string.
declare @Separator as NVarChar(64) = ';' + @EncodedCRLF + 'go;' + @EncodedCRLF + 'do something with ';
-- Characters in   @Separator   to remove from the first element in   @Result .
declare @SkipCount as Int = 4 + 2 * Len( @EncodedCRLF );
-- The result.
declare @Result as NVarChar( max ) = '';

-- Do it.
select @Result =
  Replace(
    Stuff(
      -- Specify the sorting order of the XML elements in the following   select   statement.
      ( select @Separator + name from sys.tables order by name desc for XML path(''), type).value('.[1]', 'VarChar(max)' ),
      1, @SkipCount, '' ),
    @EncodedCRLF, @CRLF );

-- Output the result.
select @Result as [Result];
-- Output the result with line breaks shown.
print @Result; -- Switch to   Messages   tab in SSMS to see result.
```